# Inequality about the Fourier transform: $\Vert u \Vert_{L^k} \le \Vert \mathcal{F}(u) \Vert_{L^m}$ (where $1 \le m \le 2$ and $m,k$ Holder conjugates)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

How can I prove the following inequality about the Fourier transform?

$$\Vert u \Vert_{L^k(\mathbb{R}^N)} \le \Vert \mathcal{F}(u) \Vert_{L^m(\mathbb{R}^N)}$$ for $1 \le m \le 2$ and $m,k$ Holder conjugates (that is $1/k + 1/m = 1)$.

---

I think it follows from the classical Hausdorff-Young inequality, but I don't know how.

---

**Hausdorff-Young**
$$\Vert \mathcal{F}(u) \Vert_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)} \le \Vert u \Vert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^N)}$$ for $1 \le q \le 2$ and $m,k$ Holder conjugates (that is $1/k + 1/m = 1)$.

Comment: It's H-Y *if* you assume $Fu\in L^m$. For general $u\in L^k$ it doesn't even make sense because the FT is not guaranteed to be in $L^m$. Questions of this type would be much better suited for MSE, though.

Comment: Or I guess you could declare the RHS to be $\infty$ if $Fu\notin L^m$, and then you're good no matter what.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, that is the convention I'm using. However, why it is H-Y is not clear to me.

Comment: If you use the correct normalization, you have $\mathcal{F}^2 u(x) = u(-x)$ which is clearly an $L^p$ isometry.

Comment: @WillieWong Would you mind writing up an answer explaining why or pointing out a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Invertibility_and_periodicity

Comment: @WillieWong I'm afraid that on Wikipedia I cannot find any proof (or even statement) useful for this situation.

Comment: The "proof", assuming the Fourier inversion formula, is one line long. The statement appears at least two times in the link I showed you (once written in the form $\mathcal{F}^2 = \mathcal{P}$). These statements all hold on Schwartz space, which is dense in any $L^p$ with $1\leq p \leq 2$. If you can't work out the details: ask on Math.SE; this is not the place for it.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. Here is the link to the MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348920/inequality-about-the-fourier-transform-vert-u-vert-lk-le-vert-mathcal If you could add an answer there with some more detail it would be great.